# Visual StudioのSetup Projectで作成したmsiファイルが SharePointを経由してダウンロード後、実行するとSymantecによって消される

Tags: c#

Visual Studio 2019を使いC#であるプログラムを作成し、Setup Projectでmsiファイル(インストーラ)を作成しました。
SharePointを経由しないでmsiファイルを実行するとインストーラが開始されます。

しかしmsi作成後、SharePointへアップロード>自身のPCへ再度ダウンロード>msi実行 するとmsiがSymantec End Pointによって消されてしまいます。
Symantec側のException設定を見なすこともできますが事情がありそれはできない状況です。
また同様に私が作ったmsiではないファイル(例えばchromeやblueprismなど)はSharePoint経由でも実行できます。

私の考えではmsiを作成するときのどこかの設定に依存するのではないかと思っています。
どなたかご教授いただけないでしょうか。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記です。
Symantec End Pointでの検知内容がこれです。
WS.Reputation.1 マルウェアとして検知されているよう。
まだ解決はしていませんが、これに対して対策を調べ続けます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: そういうノウハウは存在するかもしれませんが、公開はされないでしょう。例えばこんな記事があります。[C#作ったexeファイルがウイルス判定されてしまう（ルートキット？）](https://teratail.com/questions/62780) 今はBroadcomの製品ですか？検出した所に調査依頼してみては？[Endpoint Protection によリ検出された過剰検出を提出する](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/193903/endpoint-protection.html) ノートンの時もあったのかも？[シマンテック・セキュリティ・レスポンスにファイルを送信する方法](https://support.norton.com/sp/ja/jp/home/current/solutions/kb20090602171902EN)

Comment: まず確認すべきは「何を理由に Symantec は削除しているのか」と「SharePoint を経由する前後でファイルは本当に同一なのか (ファイルサイズや日付、チェックサムなどを確認)」辺りじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: WS.Reputation.1はマルウェアとして疑っているわけではなく、「世の中であまり知られていないもの」（新しいファイル）と言うだけです。インターネット上でダウンロードできるのに、初めて or ごく少数のユーザーしか手にしていないということは、標的型攻撃などの恐れがあるからです。多くのユーザー環境で信頼できるとして情報が集まるか、デジタル署名を付加して作成者を保証するなど、信頼性を上げるといったことが必要でしょうね。参考：https://community.norton.com/ja/forums/wsreputation1%E3%81%AE%E6%A4%9C%E5%87%BA%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6